# Spring MVC, JsonSerializer and i18n

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, jackson

I'm using a custom JsonSerializer for generating the JSON response of a Spring MVC method.
One of the fields in the response is an enum, and I would like to return a localized description of its values instead of returning the value of toString(), because I'm returning also some properties of the enum. This is part of the enum code:

```
public enum BalanceType {
    EXTERNAL_SOURCE(BalanceCurrency.EURO),
    EXTERNAL_DESTINATION(BalanceCurrency.EURO),
    MONEY_ACCOUNT(BalanceCurrency.EURO),
    CREDIT_ACCOUNT(BalanceCurrency.CREDIT);

    private BalanceCurrency currency;

    private BalanceType(BalanceCurrency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public BalanceCurrency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
}
```

I'm using this custom serializer:

```
public class BalanceTypeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BalanceType> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(BalanceType balanceType, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("value", balanceType.toString());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("currency", balanceType.getCurrency().toString());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

This is the (simplified) class used as returning value (in a list) from the Spring MVC method:

```
public class Balance {
    private ObjectId id;
    private ObjectId userId;
    @JsonSerialize(using = BalanceTypeSerializer.class)
    private BalanceType type;
    private double balance;
    private Date lastUpdated;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And this is the simplified code of the Spring MVC method itself:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/balance", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Balance> getBalanceJSON(@ModelAttribute("userId") ObjectId userId, Locale locale){
    List<Balance> balanceList = balanceRepo.findByUserId(userId);
    return balanceList;
}
```

In this method I have the locale provided by spring, but how can I get this locale passed to the serializer object?
Also, I would like to have access to the spring "MessageSource" class in the serializer via implementing MessageSourceAware, but since this class is not instantiated by Spring, I can't do it in this way, and I can't inject it neither.
Please, could you give some hints, or a better, simpler approach for doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are no way to inject `MessageSource` or `Locale` to the serializer since they are not managed by spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I can think of a couple of ways to handle this.  One solution would be to create a wrapper class for your `Balance` class that also takes a `Locale` object that you would then create a custom serializer for.  You could then manually serialize the fields with access to the `Locale`.  That's a lot of manual work though, so I wouldn't typically suggest that solution.

Another way to pass contextual data is via contextual services - in this case, the `Locale` instance is your contextual data.  For example, if you have a Spring managed bean that could hold the `Locale` of the current web request or a `ThreadContext` variable that would hold the `Locale`.  Spring has a few helper classes built for [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver) that do this.  You might also look at using the [LocaleContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html) directly too, depending on how you determine the `Locale`.  I think most of those classes use static methods, so you can utilize in non-Spring managed beans too.

Comment: I think, your second suggestion is better

Comment: Yes, I agree. The second one would be the better approach. Since I have the current request locale in the controller, I think this is the correct place to implement a helper method which aids with the translation of the enum fields. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting option 1, anyway. After some deliberation I decided that in my project, being explicit and converting to `LocalizedEntity` before serializing was better then relying on global state being correctly set up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the getLocale() Methode from SerializerProvider